# alternative log file in nginx for local requests

Tags: nginx

How can I redirect access logs to alternative file if requests come from my local network (e.g. 192.168.x.x)?
I've found [some hints](https://bjornjohansen.no/exclude-requests-from-nginx-access-log) how I can disable logs based on requester IP, but in my case I want to log these requests to another file so that for development purposes I'd see only my own logs only in that specific file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is in your referenced pages, you just need to reverse the `1`s and the `0`s.

This should work:

```
map $remote_addr $private_ip {
    ~^192\.168\.  1;
    default       0;
}
map $remote_addr $public_local {
    ~^192\.168\.  0;
    default       1;
}

server {
    ...
    # access-private.log for requests from local network
    access_log /path/to/access-private.log main if=$private_ip;

    # access.log for all other requests
    access_log /path/to/access.log main if=$public_ip;
    ...
}
```

See [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_map_module.html#map) and [this](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_log_module.html#access_log) for details.

EDIT: Actually the `geo` directive is more appropriate for mapping a `$remote_addr`:

```
geo $private_ip {
    192.168.0.0/16  1;
    default         0;
}
geo $public_local {
    192.168.0.0/16  0;
    default         1;
}
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geo_module.html#geo) for details.

Comment: that's too obvious that 0/1 needed to be reversed, question was about directing logs for requests from local network to another file. I modified your answer with proper solution